# What is the function of rebuilding indexes?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm young in the IT world, and I'm learning daily. I just started working with SQL databases, and I have lots of basic questions.

One in particular, What is the function of rebuilding indexes? I have yet to find a good answer through Google.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Indexes are rebuilt to remove fragmentation. There a thousand and one articles and blog posts on the nature of index fragmentation but @BrentOzar recently posted a particularly concise explanation in [Stop Worrying About SQL Server Fragmentation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/).

> Let’s take a step back for a second and pretend that your database is
>   a phone book organized by last name, first name.
>
> As people move into your city, we have to add them to the phone book. 
>   Ideally, each page has some empty space, and we govern that with the
>   fill factor.  When SQL Server rebuilds indexes, it uses the fill
>   factor to decide how much free space to leave on each page.  If
>   there’s not enough free space, SQL Server has to do some rearranging –
>   but it can’t exactly shove a brand new page in the middle of the phone
>   book.  The book’s already bound.  We’ll have to tack more blank pages
>   onto the end.
>
> Problem #1 – Internal Fragmentation: We’ve got a newly added page with
>   hardly any stuff on it.
>   Problem #2 – External Fragmentation: The phone book pages are out of
>   order.

Brent's recent article offers an updated perspective on one of his previous series, [Index Fragmentation Findings](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/02/index-fragmentation-findings-part-1-the-basics/). The older article highlights statistics from much older studies on the damaging effects of fragmentation, the more recent makes a case for mitigating a large percentage of the performance downsides by ensuring your database is fully cached.

Ram is now so comically cheap that it is probably the cheapest, easiest, lowest risk solution to a heavily fragmented database. Especially if the nature of the database design is such that it will naturally become fragmented despite maintenance efforts.

Answer (score 3):

The over simplified answer - Index rebuild is a way to remove index fragmentation. It drops the specified index and creates again removing fragmentation in the process. You may find [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/rebuild-indexes-online-with-sql-server-2005/249) useful